# How to use wilcards on chown command?

Tags: bash, chown

I need to use wildcards on chown command. Example:

```
# chown app:demo /opt/app/users/*/demo
```

I get the following error:

```
chown: can not access "/opt/app/users/*/demo" ': No such file or directory
```

But does not work. What can I do?

Comment: Have you permission? Maybe you nedd to use `sudo`

Comment: use centos 6 and root user.

Comment: Remove the double quotes on the directory path `chown storage:storage_clientes_bitac -R /home/storage/storage/Empresa/*/Bitacoras`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have enclosed your pattern in `"double quotes"`, which [prevent filename expansion](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/Quotes) (also called [globbing](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/globbingref.html)):

> Double quotes: "..." prevents some substitutions but allows others. Every substitution that begins with a dollar sign $ is performed, as is the legacy `...` (backtick) command substitution. Backslash escaping is also performed. *No word splitting or filename expansion is performed*.

The solution is obviously to run your command without the quotes, like jcbermu pointed out:

```
chown storage:storage_clientes_bitac -R /home/storage/storage/Empresa/*/Bitacoras
```

---

One important thing you should remember is to **post commands and error messages verbatim** when asking questions. Not everyone here likes guessing games.

Answer (score 0):

Wildcards are often problematic when not in the basename

You could do this

```
find /opt/app/users/ -name demo -exec chown app:demo \{\} \;
```

Comment: need /opt/app/users/*/demo/ but no /opt/app/users/*/demo2/demo

Comment: Oh, just one layer deep?   try `find /opt/app/users/ -maxdepth 1 -type d -name demo -exec echo \{\} found\;` to see if that works.  If it finds the right directories, change the echo into a chown command

Comment: I'm not where I can try it.  Maybe it's `-maxdepth 2` you need.